# How to allow PostgreSQL server connections from anywhere?

Tags: postgresql

I don't understand the `pg_hba.conf` documentation. It seems to say that I could add this entry:

```
host    all    all                 md5
```

or this entry

```
host    all    all     *.*.*.*/*   md5
```

to allow access from anywhere.

But not only can I not connect to my local database using my VirtualBox guest IP of `10.0.2.15` with either of these lines, if I don't have

```
host    all   all     127.0.0.1/32  md5
```

then I can no longer connect even using `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1`

**What line do I need to add to allow access from any IP (including inside Docker containers in my VirtualBox) using password authentication?**

Here's my current, standard, `hb_pga.conf` file:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all            127.0.0.1/32             md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: I see that 0.0.0.0/0 works. But why? And why don't the ones above work?

Comment: I may seem a dumb question, but what error message are you getting when you try to log in?

Comment: Something about pg_hba.conf doesn't allow this address

Comment: Yes sometimes precise wording of an error is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(All the below is based on the [documentation for Postgres 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), but I'm not aware of any major changes for this syntax, so it should apply to anything vaguely recent.)

As far as I know, the line

```
host    all    all                 md5
```

isn't valid syntax. When using the `host` record type, the following formats are available

```
host       database  user  address              auth-method  [auth-options]
host       database  user  IP-address  IP-mask  auth-method  [auth-options]
```

so a minimum of four additional arguments, whereas you've only provided three.

As per your comment, the line

```
host    all    all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

will work to allow connections from all IP address (based on subsequent password authentication). The `/0` is a mask for which bits (literally the bits) of the IP address to validate against. `/0` means you want to ignore the whole thing, i.e. **allow all addresses**. The mask `1.2.3.4/0` would mean exactly the same thing. It's not usually best practice to allow access from anywhere, but if you're dealing with non-public facing VMs or Docker containers then it's fine.

If you're using IPv6 connections, the syntax is very similar:

```
host    all    all ::/0 md5
```

For what it's worth, I've never come across the syntax

```
host    all    all     *.*.*.*/*   md5
```

Comment: You might also need to add an entry for IPv6 connections

Comment: There's only a danger on public databases if someone has your password, right?  As long as that is supersecret then there's nothing they can do even if you allow any connections?

Comment: Sort of. It's better for the connections to be denied entirely, that way no one knows there's even a database there. You can deter a thief by locking your door, but if you can hide your house entirely then why not do that?

Comment: @Richard: They could still try to brute-force the password. Even if they don't succeed, it's still a headache. Best not to give them the opportunity.

Comment: Thank you finally was able to connect using your answer